# Example of a metric group over $\mathbb{R}_0^+$

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces

Do you know an example of a function $d:\mathbb{R}_0^+\times\mathbb{R}_0^+\to \mathbb{R}_0^+$ for which the following properties hold? Or can you prove this does not exist?

1. There exists an $e\in \mathbb{R}_0^+$ such that $d(a,e) = d(e,a) = a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}_0^+$.
2. For all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}_0^+$, we have $d(a,d(b,c)) = d(d(a,b),c)$.
3. For all $a \in\mathbb{R}_0^+$ there exists a $b\in\mathbb{R}_0^+$ such that $d(a,b)=e$.
4. For all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_0^+$, we have $d(a,b) = d(b,a)$.
5. For all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}_0^+$, we have $d(a,b) \leq d(a,c)+d(c,b)$.
6. If $d(a,b)=0$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_0^+$, we have that $a=b$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Is $\mathbb R^+_0=[0,+\infty)$ ? If not, you should write $d:\mathbb R^+_0\times\mathbb R^+_0\to [0,+\infty)$, or (6) would be true by null hypothesis.  2) In (6) do you also want $\forall a\in \mathbb R_0^+,\, d(a,a)=0$ ?

Comment: 1) Yes, $\mathbb{R}_0^+ = [0,+\infty)$. 2) Yes. I thought what I wrote meant that, actually.

Comment: In that case, (1) and (6) imply that $0=d(e,e)=e$.  Thus $e=0$, and condition (3) is implied by (6), since for all $a$, we have $d(a,a)=0=e$.  Now your question becomes: is there an associative metric on the set of non-negative reals? This question [has been answered on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/16214/39640); the answer seems to be that such a metric exists, but the proof is non-constructive.

Comment: Thank you, @Pierre-GuyPlamondon, I didn't realize that.